# Not able to properly implement import for python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, import, python-import

I am trying to import class called storePass() from test2 into test

I have done this->

test1->

```
import smtplib
from test2 import storePass

Gmail = storePass()
a = Gmail.returnPass()
```

test2->

```
class storePass():
    Gmail_pass = "xcmsijw19021"
    def returnPass(self):
        return self.Gmail_pass
```

However I am getting the following error ->

```
TypeError: returnPass() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

When I try to write the code as follows ->

```
class storePass():
    Gmail_pass = "xcmsijw19021"
    def returnPass(self):
        return self.Gmail_pass

Gmail = storePass()
a = Gmail.returnPass()
```

I am getting no errors and I can execute print(a) without any problem.
So It's certainly something wrong with my import !

EDIT : Both test1 and test2 are in same directory !

Comment: Do you have a stale `test2.pyc` file lying around created from an earlier version of `test2.py`? You are almost certainly not importing the code you think you are. One way to tell would be to change the name of `returnPass` in `test2.py`, but don't change the call in `test1.py`. If you still get the same error, you know `test2.py` isn't being used, and `storePass` is being imported from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to run your code and it works on my python 2.7.6 interpreter.
I print `a` and it gives me as a result `xcmsijw19021`.

This is the code I used:
`file.py`

```
import smtplib
from test2 import storePass
Gmail = storePass()
a = Gmail.returnPass()
print a
```

`test2.py`

```
class storePass():
    Gmail_pass = "xcmsijw19021"
    def returnPass(self):
        return self.Gmail_pass
```

Then I did run `python file.py` and it prints me correctly the output.

I think it's some interpreter/ide problem maybe?

Python3 works aswell, by using print(a)

Comment: It shouldnt depend on any such factors as far as I know !

Answer (score 0):

i tried and ran it on Ubuntu 16.04 python 2.7 and it worked as expected. make sure your two files are at the same folder or that the test2 path is in PYTHONPATH.

anyway to **F.Leone** python does not have a compiler and from what i know it does not depend on specific IDE.

Comment: They are both in the same file !
Else I would have got an error regarding import not conditional :/ !

Comment: Python *is* a compiled language; it just doesn't compile to native machine code.

Comment: i wrote same folder! no need to be rude! read the comment before you lash out.